# Sending information from one webform to another

Tags: c#, vb.net, webforms, parameters, asp.net

i'm generating HyperLinks, all of them (depending on the circunstance, could be 1, 2 or 1000) send to the same webform:

from default.aspx
to envia.aspx

i can't use session, or anything i already know, because i can't create as many methods i want (that would not be good, due to possible large numbers)

example, there are three lines i print on demand:
house [link]
car   [link]
flower[link]

i want the three links to load the same aspx webform sending as a parameter a string with these lines.

i don't care if the answer is in vb.net or in c#, anything you could help it's ok (i'm using vb.net though)

Comment: I noticed you said you were new.  Please remember to mark the appropriate answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you use Query String?

```
envia.aspx?param1=something&param2=somethingelse
```

in envia.aspx:

```
string param1 = Request["param1"];
string param2 = Request["param2"];
```

Comment: There is a limit on what the size of the querystring can be so if he has thousands of links, this will choke.

Comment: 256 character you can send into querystring .. it is a maxlimit of querystiring

Comment: i won't send lots of parameters, just one, but i have to be able to send one of lots of parameters.

Comment: no .. only 256 character only.. i give. you example. wait a min

Comment: Response.Redirect("Edit.aspx?eid="+ e_id + "&ename=" + e_name + "&socname=" + soc_name + "&city=" + city + "&state=" + state  + "&birthdate=" + birth_date + "&qualification=" + qualification  + "&post=" + post );

Comment: give me reply.. if you dont get it . or get it.

Comment: hey, it worked! thank all of you guys very much! this is my first programming question in stack overflow that comes to a solving thanks to you guys!
if i could i'd vote it up, but i have no reputation.. i guess my questions are too noob for someone to find them interesting and i can't answer many yer =(
Thanks again!

Comment: @nickyt - it doesn't matter if he has thousands of links as long as each link doesn't have a querystring above the limit, so I'm not sure what your actual point is

Comment: @Marek - I misunderstood his question. I thought he was putting thousands of items in the querystring of one url.

Comment: ahh, in that case it would indeed be a bad solution

Answer (score 0):

What about crosspage postbacks? Only used it once, but this sounds like a good candidate for it. See Cross-Page Posting in ASP.NET Web Pages, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx